# Creating a dictionary from two iterables and consuming both of them

Tags: python, dictionary, iterable

Suppose I have two lists and I want to make a dictionary from them. Like:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> dict(zip(l, x))
{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

This works as I'd want it to and since the lists are not of equal length, the elements `4` and `5` are left out and there is no corresponding value for them. That is as expected.

But what if I want a value, say `None` for the keys in `l`? I'd want the output to be:

`{1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: None, 5: None}`

One of the solutions I thought was to iterate over both, compare their lengths and append `None` where required. I have a solution that works also, but I was wondering whether it can be done in a much easier and shorter way perhaps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use

```
dict(itertools.izip_longest(l, x))
# {1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c', 4: None, 5: None}
```

Comment: Heh, perfect! I was guessing something like this existed!

Comment: BTW: on Python 3, it's called "zip_longest" (without the leading "i").